# Is it possible to declare the type with 'this' keyword like that in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Example:

```
// ===== Declaration ===== //
class A {
  CONSTS_TYPE: { [key: string]: [any] }
  CONSTS: { [key in keyof this['CONSTS_TYPE']]: key }
  foo<T extends keyof this['CONSTS_TYPE'] | string>(
    type: T,
    callback: (...args: T extends keyof this['CONSTS_TYPE'] ? this['CONSTS_TYPE'][T] : any) => any
  ) { /** some implementation*/ }
}
class B extends A {
  CONSTS_TYPE: {
    aa: [number],
    bb: [string]
  }
  // Here is the problem
  // Type '{ aa: "aa"; bb: "bb"; }' is not assignable to type '{ [key in keyof this["CONSTS_TYPE"]]: key; }'.(2322)
  CONSTS: { [key in keyof this['CONSTS_TYPE']]: key } = {
    aa: 'aa',
    bb: 'bb'
  }
}

// ===== Call ===== //
const b = new B;
b.foo(b.CONSTS.aa, (arg) => {
  // so that i can know 'arg' is a 'number' type
  arg // number type
});
```

it works well, but not too well.

i know '// @ts-ignore' will work really well

but I think there may be other solutions

[[Playground Link]](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=28&ssc=4&pln=7&pc=1#code/PTAEF5M0BEFMDGAbAhgJxQFwJYHsB2EU4oIAUMigM5WgCCoA3maKAMIDyAcgMoAqPAPp8AmgAUAogC4moANoBrOAE8ZVTGmz4A5gF0ZclPmW7QAXxbtu-HjMbyly0FtCPcAM1CYAFtipyAck5eAWFxCQDdfVcVc0t3XFwAHj5QOAAPTDh8ABNaN08fP0DgmzDJSNAAH1B1TR0APgAKS1ZMZQAHOBk+ABpW0AQUJCQAIxQEBRkmgDo59G0qHrTM7LyY5Q8vX38g61DRCtMAfm3ivZChQ4jdOT5TGSNlAEoIBtAny1f7YAAqX9quAAtnBnECOkg4CD8JgsHh8L8wBYLJQaKAAEIrLK5WgMZisUoHcJ2AYoFAGfAAVyBozgaF0-VYrFGowMdS0eksFlYIFAAAk6aC-NtQR00LhRpCgZZeXxOqCAvYyTIAERklUAblALNVLM15gCzlo+FwmA+NGw2nwKEloMwuC88tAiocsRcBTO-hVhKu4RVURkji1ZgCMyaACYAMzh8PPSw+uyupzulRbIq7H3lG7RRzmCBMUnk51kgKMpk650sgJcsgWMi84gkNjDJBEKCkYAUAjqbX5-BwADuGI1ZFGMwSuCaY59MxZvVATQWr3A73xHcB2ywzkGRlcJqHAQWhuFKGdVJpdMN7S6lgW6-PtLQjpvZmeGqAA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found a solution

```
// ===== Declaration ===== //
class A<T extends Record<string, [any?]>> {

    foo<U extends keyof T | string>(
        type: U,
        callback: (...args: U extends keyof T ? T[U] : any) => any
    ) { /** some implementation*/ }
}

type T_BConstsType = {
    aa: [number],
    bb: [string]
}

class B extends A<T_BConstsType> {

    CONSTS: { [key in keyof T_BConstsType]: key } = {
        aa: 'aa',
        bb: 'bb'
    }
}

// ===== Call ===== //
const b = new B;
b.foo(b.CONSTS.aa, (arg) => {
    // so that i can know 'arg' is a 'number' type
    arg // number type
});
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=2&ssc=16&pln=1&pc=1#code/PTAEF5M0BEFMDGAbAhgJxQFwJYHsB2EU4oIAUMigM5WgCCAPACqhwAemc+AJrQEqJcabgyqY02fAHMANKADaKfAE8A-AF0AfJtABvMmVBHQAM1y4GAVVYcuvUAGs4y3CdAsAPqDETpmgBSGxsGYygAOcABcoJYyQcFGCChISABGKAgO0f4AdHnoUlTR1uycPLROLm4squ7yluqg0UrKAJQQOi3xoO26pABU-d64ALZwoNgjYUhwY-iYWHj4-WAAvmTrZKER7gD6AEIAwgRiVEzh4yT6wSgo0fL4AK4jqXBo6nHBqan3PpJS6g2BkoNFA+xsZXsjCYB2O+FO5wiOn03UOAHkAHIAZSYWOifXklQmhEqrj2RxOmDOF3U0SJqwgem6NzuoAA5Lc2Z8EkZvtE2d82d11psQEQoKBDskkOLoOQEJTQKlGfg4AB3MEAbjIqRyZlw-l16OxuJytzk-gK7XAyO6YqouFAmAAFlgJqAkiT8LgNRy0FI2RNaCh2U8Xm9A9s4N0CqQwGHXmgnRcNq1NUA)

Answer (score 1):

So, I think there are some problem going on with your code :

- You should avoid using `@ts-ignore` as much as you can.
- `aa: 'aa',` is not a number and should have raised you an error. It didn't cause of the way you have implemented it
- in `...args: T`, `T` is an array and not one parameter as you think
- Why use `...args` in `foo` ?

---

Here is what I think could be a soluce to you :

```
// ===== Declaration ===== //
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

abstract class A {
  abstract CONSTS: { [key: string]: any }

  foo<T extends ValueOf<this['CONSTS']>>(
    type: T,
    callback: (arg: T) => any
  ) { /** some implementation*/ }
}

class B extends A {
  CONSTS: {
    aa: number,
    bb: string
  } = {
    aa: 5,
    bb: 'bb'
  }
}

// ===== Call ===== //
const b = new B;
b.foo(b.CONSTS.bb, (arg) => {
  // so that i can know 'arg' is a 'string' type
  arg // string type
});
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=28&pc=4#code/PTAEF5M0BEFMDGAbAhgJxQFwJYHsB2EU4oIAUJgJ4AOcoAaikgK5wDyAZgDwAqAfBFA8A2gGs4lXByEBdANxkyKAEYBnTBgSZQyFKtWgAgqADeZUKBXrN2gMJsAcgGUeTgFynQYiR+vZ8AOYyHij4lKAAvooWHLi4vKBwAB6YcPgAJgaMLOzcmAAW2KrCAOT2zq4lMnx8ABTmFqBUtB48ADQNFghMSMooCKIetegBrQCUEAKhlA0TJqQAVAugqrgAtnTYa9RIcBv4mFh4+AtgUVFkuvqgAEKJKWmZRqYN5S7uL42WKB74zGvKOBoDpfZTKXwafwBBoRQRmL4oH6gACsIMaYI8JTBJRhZAuICIUFAth6hOg5AQBHUoGUgnwcAA7rcFMoAHSxXC1NlvVyssFtUDDNABCbgATw0hgVZNfJYUDYHShUCifC4JklEYleUGFCgEp+QJa5pwBojSUrSGBJo0E0RMZyIA)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't a generic class what you're actually looking for instead?

```
declare class Foo<T extends Record<string, [any]>> {
  CONST_TYPES: T;
  CONSTS: {
    [K in keyof T]: K
  }

  constructor(types: T);

  foo<U extends keyof T>(type: U, callback: (value: T[U]) => any): any;
}

const foo = new Foo({ aa: [42], bb: ['foo'] });

foo.foo(foo.CONSTS.bb, (arg) => {
  arg // [string]
})
```